# Mark story as viewed on Instagram web

Tags: instagram

Has anyone noticed that viewing a story on Instagram's web platform does not register as being viewed?

Unlike when accessed through the application, watching the story does mark it as viewed and the user's profile goes to the end of the line.

Is there a fix for that when using Instagram on the web?

Comment: It seems to me the issue was resolved by Instagram